# How to reinitialize a package on each routing in Vue?

Tags: javascript, datatables, bootstrap-4, vue-router, vue.js

I've found a [tool for table management](https://datatables.net/) and I love it. The only problem is that it needs initializing as shown below, which means that it only gets called once - when the page's been loaded.

```
mounted: () => {
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    $("table").DataTable();
  }
}
```

I've put the code in the *mounted* section and I also tried to use *created*. For some reason (probably rendering order), I have to keep it in *ready* method - otherwise it doesn't come up.

This poses two problems for me. Firstly, I'm reusing the same component as a matrix view in multiple components (it's dynamically set up based on the store). Secondly, when I navigate from the page and then go back, it doesn't reinitialize.

How should I make the code inside *ready* method to run each time the component gets in the view?

I've googled a bit but it's a not so common issue and I'm out of ammo. The best hit I got was [the life cycle of the component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) where I couldn't see anything ground breaking. I also found that the [data table instance needs to be destroyed](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3) but that only helps if I get to invoke the stuff, which seems not to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to do following:

```
mounted () {
    $("table").DataTable();
}
```

as [$(document).ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) detects that the document is ready, but in vue case, [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) is called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el, which should be equivalent of document.ready.

I have also checked in vue 2.x.x that mounted gets called if you navigate from the page and then go back.

---

If this code is dependent on data being loaded and re-rendering of component, you can use [updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) instead of mounted which  is called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and patched.

```
updated () {
    $("table").DataTable();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. But here's the weird part - it doesn't work with the code you suggest. However, if we put a tiny delay, then it does. So this is fine: *setTimeout(() => { $("table").DataTable(); }, 100);* but if we put 100 to 0, it doesn't render. It's like there's a tiny delay (be that in Vue or in DataTable or both), that I need to wait out. And I have huge issues with creating an architecture based on a bunch of timeouts, hehe. It's a recipe for disaster and a clear sign of bad design. Where should I hook in the data table creation **past** mounting?

Comment: @KonradViltersten as you are saying that it works after delay, is this dependent on data load? if this is than you can try [updated](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) hook which is called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and patched.

Comment: It seems to do the trick. Please add that to the answer as well so I can accept it and +1 it. The life cycle diagram on Vue's page is very misleading - some of the hooks are depicted as circles and some as boxes (same browny color of the border but I didn't see that because the background of the boxes is white). So I thought that the only hooks available were *mounted* and *destroyed*.

Comment: I noticed that you used *updated(){...}* instead of, as I usually write, *updated:()=>{}*. Is there any difference semantically speaking?

Comment: @KonradViltersten This is tricky, what I can understand from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) is if we write without `=>`, function defines `this` as the global object and not `this` of enclosing function. Hope this helps, however I myself am not very clear about it.

Comment: @I'll take your advice into consideration. Thanks. In meantime - feel free to take a whack at [this weirdness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347977/cant-access-fields-rendered-in-v-for-in-vue) I've stumbled upon.