# Can't access data in getter when binding by v-if but can access when rendered by v-for in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

I have a table that renders based on computed properties like this. Notice how each row gets its style based on its contents. This works dandy.

```
computed: { rows: function () { return this.$store.getters.tableRows; }, ... }

<tr v-for="row in rows" v-bind:class="rowClass(row)">
  <td v-for="(item, key, index) in row.columns" v-bind:class="classy(index)">{{item}}</td>
</tr>
```

I also wanted to add a collective info outside of the table, so I set up the following messaging conditional.

```
computed: {
  finished: function () {
    return this.rows.length === 5;
  },
  whoopsie: function () {
    return this.rows[this.rows.length - 1].columns.elapsed < 0;
  }, ...
}

<div v-if="finished" class="alert alert-success">Done.</div>
<div v-if="whoopsie" class="alert alert-warning">Oops.</div>
```

The first one works just as expected. However, the second one throws me an error that *cannot read property 'columns' of undefined*, which looks insane as I can clearly see the data on the screen and the *length* property is definitely not zero.

I tried to use *debugger* command to poke around there but it seems not to be invoked at that part of the code. I know the code gets executed because changing *return false* to *return true* does render a difference. And *debugger* seems to work at other places in the code. Weird...

I tried to store the value to a global variable as shown below. Poking in that variable from console window produces precisely the values I was expecting. I can't understand what's going on there but it's definitely some black magic.

```
whoopsie: function () {
  window.wtf = this.rows[this.rows.length - 1];
  // return true;
  return false;
}, ...
```

1. What can I do to get my hands on the values in the computed property?
2. Why doesn't it do what a sane person would expect it to?
3. How can debugger be invoked in there?

**Edit**

The store has the following getter.

```
tableRows: function(state) { return state.dataTable.rows; }
```

It's being assigned to the following object. Each row in the data has an ID and a container *columns*.

```
const rows = [];
for (let i = 0; data && i < data.length; i++)
rows.push({
  id: data[i].id,
  columns: {
    ...
    elapsed: recalculate(data[i].span)
  }
});
```

I want to bind to two computed properties that will be true if the number of rows in the table is 5 (that's *finished*) and if the value of *elapsed* on the last of the rows is negative (that's *woopsie*). That why I'm declaring those two (and only the first one's working).

Comment: How does `this.$store.getters.tableRows` looks like?

Comment: @saurabh It's an array of objects - id and columns. Columns is an object with fields corresponding to the contents of the table. [ {id: xxx, columns: {a:1,b:2}] I assumed that it can't be the source of the issue because I get it to give me the right values in the console. And the error message is that the row is undefined...

Comment: Investigating it further, I realize that the problem might be with the fact that the getter returns empty array for `whoopsie` but it returns something filled when it's binding in the table. As in evaluating `this.$store.getters.tableRows;` produces different results for `v-if` and `v-for`.

Answer (score 0):

Error seems in this particular code to me, You can not have `(item, key, index)` with `v-for` with an array of objects, that syntax is only available [with object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-v-for), see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sj8obmzb/).

so You need something like following:

```
<tr v-for="row in rows" v-bind:class="rowClass(row)">
  <td v-for="(item, index) in row.columns" v-bind:class="classy(index)">{{item}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It might be me not explaining it well. Let me try again. The table rendering is working perfectly. Since I'm iterating through the **object** named columns, I need *item,key,index*, there. The problem occurs **outside** the table. While the table presents one *TR* per each row in `rows`, I also show an aggregated status based on all the rows. If you check out the edit, I'm showing some more code there.